# Wpf не скачивает пакеты с NuGet

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget

Выдает ошибку
Не удалось установить пакет «Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.9». Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «.NETFramework,Version=v4.8», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой. Дополнительную информацию можно получить у автора пакета.

Comment: ef core 6 не работает на .net 4.8, обновите свой проект на .net 6, там вроде wpf уже есть, тогда и ef core можно будет установить

Comment: Версия проекта который вы сделали слишком старая для новейшей версии EFCore, не используйте .NET Framework, используйте .NET Core. Либо обновитесь до версии 4.8 и установите EF

Comment: Русским по белому же написано, в чем проблема. Скачиваемый пакет несовместим с вашим проектом.

Comment: Всем спасибо большое, в проблеме разобрался.